# Allowed Memory Size of *** Bytes Exhausted

Tags: php, memory, limit

I want to process a large XML-File, but when I start my Script I get a

> Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of *** Bytes Exhausted

Does PHP not clear/override the memory when I start my script again?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code before reading the file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Change size according to your need.

Comment: I already have set allowed memory to 850Mb

Comment: Just restart your apache and then check it again

Comment: is is a shared server.. i cant restart it :/

Comment: In case of shared hosting it is not possible to do so. Just check the phpinfo.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase Allowed Memory Size from php.ini file on your server.

Comment: I already have set allowed memory to 850Mb

Answer (score 0):

The memory is limited either by your hosting environment or by you php.ini file you may want to try upping this limit, otherwise check with your web host and see how much ram you have been allotted.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```

Comment: I already have set allowed memory to 850Mb

Comment: it's probably due to the limit imposed on your account by your hosting provider. The limit here is only a soft limit, it will not exceed the capabilities of your hosting environment